# Input text value into a multiple data list and have option to remove them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input text box where user enter model number and the model number must be displayed in multiple data lists when user click add button. The user has must also have the option to remove the selected model number in the multiple data lists. I have created the HTML code and Javascript code, but the javascript is not adding.

What is is the best approach to my problem? I'm very newbie to javascript.

Hey is my code:

```
<html lang=en>
<head>
<title>Add To Datalist</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="bootstrap_3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap_3.3.7/fonts/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <br/>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <legend>Compatible Devices </legend>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modelNo" name="modelNo" placeholder="Enter Name Here"><br/>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addModNo"><button class="btn btn-info">Add </button></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeModNo"><button class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button></a>   
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6"> 
                    <div class="listfromPopulatedModelNumber" id="listfromPopulatedModelNumber">                                                
                        <select id="listfromPopulatedModelNo" multiple="multiple" col=10 rows=10>
                                <option></option>
                                <option></option>
                                <option></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
            .ready(
                    function() {
                        var count = 2;
                        $("#addModNo")
                                .click(
                                        function() {
                                            $('#listfromPopulatedModelNo')
                                                    .last()
                                                    .after(
                                                            '#modelNo');
                                            count++;
                                        });
                        $("#removeModNo").click(function() {                            
                            $('#modelNumber > option:selected').remove();
                            count--;
                        });
                    });
</script>
```

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: `$("#ddModNo")` ?? Please review your own code and fix what you can

Comment: Also `$(function(){` is a shorthand for DOM ready and there's no need to have a DOM ready nested inside a DOM ready `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: `cnt++` where have you defined that `cnt`??

Comment: thanks, @Roko I saw I put the wrong id. I fixed it but still no luck.

Comment: Open Developer console, console should be your best friend from today on, read the errors it throws, fix them.

Comment: Ok thanks about that again, I have done that by catching my console, sorry m still learning. I did fix the stuff you pointed out. I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Sure cause you still did not fixed this line: `after(
                                                            ''count  + '#modelNo'');
                                            count ++;`

Comment: Thanks, I saw it. I fixed the error on the console. It takes the #modelNo  when I add, every time I add it writes  #modelNo but outside my data list. I have updated my code again.

Comment: The `#modelNo` get appended outside your `#listfromPopulatedModelNo`?

Comment: Yes, @King still I'm working on it.

Comment: Is this the outout you get ? `#modelNo` get appended outside your `#listfromPopulatedModelNo`?Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/ag0mwufd/

Comment: Thanks @King. Thats what i get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. I have updated solution for you here [Updated Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/Kingzp/ag0mwufd/4/)

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

       $('#addModNo').click( function(){
                var input = $("input[name='modelNo']").val();
                 console.log(input);
                $('#listfromPopulatedModelNo').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+ input +"</option>");

         });

         $('#removeModNo').click(function(){
            $('option:selected').each( function() {
                var input = $("input[name='modelNo']").val();
                $('#listfromPopulatedModelNo').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+ input +"</option>");
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks @King, I no longer the Remove button by the way. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I helped out. You should learn more on java-script here https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp and jquery here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp seings you are a beginner. This will help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks again for the links